# Validation rule that prevents saving a lookup if that lookup value (Product) doesn't already exist on Opportunity

Tags: validation-rule, opportunity-lineitem, master-detail

I have an object - myCustomObject__c that is has a Master-Detail relationship to Opportunity. On this object I also have a lookup to Product.

I want to throw a validation error if a user tries to populate the lookup to Product that does not already exist on an Opportunity. Something like this: "Product is not listed on the Opportunity and cannot be added to myCustomObject."

Am I overthinking this? I thought about maybe having a list of comma separated ProductIds on the Opportunity and checking the following in a validation rule:

```
myCustomObject__c.ProductIds.CONTAINS(Product__c)
```

But then I'm not sure what the best way to maintain that list outside of Apex would be... or if it is even feasible...

Comment: a validation rule on an object can't look at fields in children objects; only at fields on itself or lookup objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you need `Apex` for this, and I don't think storing the `Id` values in a separate field is worth the trouble. Using a collection based approach, you need to generate a `Map<Id, Set<Id>>`, where the key is the `Id` of the `Opportunity`, and the value is the collection of all related `Product Id` values.

```
public static void validateProducts(List<MyCustomObject__c> records)
{
    Map<Id, Set<Id>> opportunityToProducts = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
    for (MyCustomObject__c record : records)
        opportunityToProducts.put(record.Opportunity__c, new Set<Id>());
    // now you have a keyset with all Opportunity Ids

    for (OpportunityLineItem oli : [
        SELECT OpportunityId, PricebookEntry.Product2Id
        FROM OpportunityLineItem
        WHERE OpportunityId IN :opportunityToProducts.keySet()
    ])
        opportunityToProducts.get(oli.OpportunityId)
            .add(oli.PricebookEntry.Product2Id);
    // now for any individual Opportunity Id you can determine
    // which Product Ids have been added

    for (MyCustomObject__c record : records)
    {
        Set<Id> validProductIds = opportunityToProducts.get(record.Opportunity__c);
        if (!validProductIds.contains(record.Product__c))
            record.addError(Label.Missing_Product);
            // if you really do not want to use a label, you can use the below instead
            // record.addError('Some custom message');
    }
}
```

The above functionality can be called from a trigger on `MyCustomObject__c`. I recommend using a `Custom Label` to store the error message you want to use so it can be easily configured if needed.